# Not able to sign in using facebook and google plus in android live application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on an android application in which I have two social Login Facebook and Google Plus.

For Facebook integration I have generated release key so that it will work on live app.
Using below command I was able to create key hash:

```
**keytool -exportcert -alias androidreleasekey -keystore E:\app\release.keystore | C:\Users\Amit\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | C:\Users\Amit\Downloads\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe base64**
```

For Google Plus integration I have used release command to generate release SHA1 key and using that key I have used it in Firebase to get JSON file.

Using below command I was able to create SHA1 for release:

```
**keytool -list -v -keystore E:\Android\app\keystore.jks -alias android**
```

But problem is this I have created signed apk and it was working perfectly with Facebook and G+ login but when I am using live apk it is not working with Facebook and G+ login. Why?

Comment: Did you add your fingerprint to Facebook App?

Comment: Yes, I have added. Now Google Plus integration is not working at all

Comment: _SHA_ will be different for debug and release apks.

Comment: Yes, I used differnt

Comment: Please follow this https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started